# how can i manually add libraries to my website hosting server

Tags: asp.net, iis

My website host server's system is horribly old (btw, it's called 123-reg, avoid it like the plague if you can)
it seems it doesn't even have the linq library. Is it possible to upload the linq.dll library to my bin folder and load it? where is the file?

Answer (score 1):

This would naturally be available for sites running .net 3.5 or higher.

however, to answer your question of adding it..

You can right-click on your sites Bin folder in Visual Studio and "Add Reference".

Select the .Net tab on the top and you will find it as `System.Data.Linq`

Word of caution though, if you're host doesn't support .net 3.5 or higher it won't work.

Comment: Linq is in my computer. I am using VS2012. But it's absent in my web hosting server. >.<

Comment: Yes, i understand that. What i mean is what version of asp.net is 123-Reg running on your site. if it's less than 3.5 your going to have a hard time...

Comment: Ok, so assuming your website is running on the .net 3.5 framework, do what I proposed in my answer then - add a reference. this will put the DLL in your bin folder. You can then upload it.

Comment: my linq library is checked by default. But there is no linq library in my bin or app_code

Comment: You will find the file on your PC then. C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319

Comment: I would say you're out of luck - if your server old it's likely to be 2.0 - call them to confirm, don't go by their feature list on their site.